# Why Is my div going under another element when I give It a negative margin

Tags: html, css

So I have a div `(.section-page-layout)` with a margin of `(margin-top:-200px)` and the div `(.section-page-layout)` is going under the div `(.section-page-header)` where it should be going over it. I uploaded the code to a demo link where you can fiew it with Firebug or whatnot. I have also included my code.

http://kmgp.us/stackoverflow/section_page_template.html

Thanks in advance!

CSS CODE

```
/* Header */
.section-page-header {
    background: url("../img/frontcover.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 727px;
    min-width: 1280px;
}
.section-page-header-title_container {
    width: 1280px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.section-page-header-title {
    margin-top: 83px;
    border-top: 7px #5b461c solid;
    width: 1170px;
    float: left;
    height: 167px;
    background: #000000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
    /* IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
    /* IE 5-7 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    /* Gecko */
    -moz-opacity: 0.9;
    /* Safari 1.x */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.9;
    /* CSS3 */
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.section-page-header-title h1 {
    font-family: 'QuicksandBook';
    margin-left: 147px;
    margin-top: 46px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.section-page-header-title p {
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 147px;
    font-family: 'junctionregularRegular';
    color: #ff9900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.section-page-layout-container {
    background:#984B09;
    background: url('../img/section-page-oj_gradient-background.png') repeat-y;
    background-size:contain;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.section-page-layout {
    width: 1280px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    margin-top:-200px;
}
.left-section-container {
    width: 585px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<!-- ===============
=== Section Page Template
=============== -->
<header class="section-page-header">
    <div class="section-page-header-title_container">
        <div class="section-page-header-title">
            <h1>ABOUT <b>US</b></h1>
            <p>A simple glance into our company</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<section class="section-page-layout-container">
    <div class="section-page-layout">
        <div class="left-section-container">
            <header> </header>
            <div class="left-section">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-module-section">

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="clear"><!-- Clear --></div>
```

Comment: try adding `z-index: 100` on the div you want on top

Comment: No that didn't fix it

Comment: ah, you have `overflow: hidden` on the container so when the div moves up it gets hidden under the edge of the container

Comment: But then the gradient dispersers?

Comment: @JakeZeitz He's talking about the Yellow Background image. It's a 1px high by 2700px wide image.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16248781/gone.JPG

Comment: @MiniRagnarok the height is supposed to be dynamic based on how much content is added within the area

Comment: @kmgilbert100 Notice I said the image size. That size doesn't change. What does is the display of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `overflow:hidden` on a parent element then when you move the child outside of the parent it will be hidden.

Comment: But then the gradient dispersers?

Comment: Add `display:inline-block;` to `.section-page-layout-container`

Comment: That fixes the background problem but then adds this strange black space at the bottom of the element between it and the footer?

Comment: @kmgilbert100 For some reason you have `line-height` set on your `body`. It should be zero.

Comment: Removing that causes more spacing

Comment: @kmgilbert100 The answer to your original question is the one I gave up top. You have a lot of other issues with this site but I'm not going to fix them all for you. Everything else that has gone wrong since `overflow:hidden` is because of the way you've made the site. Try fixing things before you ask any more questions. Then you'll get experience.

Comment: finding the right `overflow:hidden` might be tricky. Open dev tools > Computed > search for "overflow" and then go through the dom hierarchy. There might be more than one element which overflow setting you will have to change.